# Is there a way to reduce lagging of a guideline that follows the mouse pointer?

Tags: svg, d3.js

I have a vertical guideline across my svg that follows the mouse pointer, but right now it's kind of slow to update its position, something that's especially noticeable with rapid mouse movements. Is there a way to reduce this lag?

Current code:

```
svg.on("mousemove", function(d) {
    svg.select(".guideline")
        .attr("x1", d3.mouse(this)[0]-1)
        .attr("x2", d3.mouse(this)[0]-1);

});

svg.on("mouseover", function(d) {
    svg.append("line")
        .attr("class", "guideline")
        .attr("y1", margin[0])
        .attr("y2", height+margin[0])
        .attr("opacity", originOpacity)
        .attr("stroke", "#333")
        .attr("pointer-events", "none");

});

svg.on("mouseout", function(d) {
    svg.select(".guideline").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You are selecting the line on every mousemove, keep the line in a variable instead:

```
var line = svg.append("line")
        .attr("class", "guideline")
        .attr("y1", margin[0])
        .attr("y2", height+margin[0])
        .attr("opacity", 0)
        .attr("stroke", "#333")
        .attr("pointer-events", "none");

svg.on("mousemove", function(d) {

    line
        .attr("x1", d3.event.pageX-1)
        .attr("x2", d3.event.pageY-1);

});

svg.on("mouseover", function(d) {
  line.attr("opacity", originOpacity);
});

svg.on("mouseout", function(d) {
    line.attr("opacity", 0);
});
```

Comment: This helped to reduce some of the lagging, thank you for that, but I was hoping there was a way to reduce it even more since there still is a very obvious delay when moving the mouse pointer.

Comment: `d3.event.pageX` and `.pageY` might be faster, I've updated the answer. Beyond that I'm afraid You've already optimized all you could, there's always going to be a slight lag behind the mouse.

Comment: I dont' think it's the `select` that is causing the problem with performance, I think it's the rapid modifications to the DOM that the browser can't keep up with.

Answer (score 3):

I am having the same problem, but I noticed two things:

1. If you look at High Charts, they have implemented (in their JS library) a similar vertical guideline, which doesn't lag behind so much. So it is possible to do it. See for example: [here](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/)
2. I use a  container element, to which I added an SVG element, to which I added a group (g) element with a coordinate translation/transformation, like so:

HTML:

```
<div id="d3-container"></div>
```

JS:

```
var svg = d3.select("#d3-container")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .attr("id","d3-svg")
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .attr("id","d3-canvas");
```

The interesting thing is, when I bind mouse events (using the code above in the first answer) to the various elements, I get very different performance: when I bind it to the "d3-canvas" group my guided line is very slow and lags behind, when I bind it to its parent svg element ("d3-svg") it is already faster, and if I bind it to the div ("d3-container") I get the fastest performance (although it is still not as quick as High Stock though). So I am thinking the coordinate transformation adds a lot of overhead to mouse events, but somehow either D3 or SVG is also not optimized for mouse events.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than updating the attributes on every `mousemove`, you could add a couple millisecond delay:

```
var lastMove, elapsed;
svg.on("mousemove", function(d) {

    elapsed = Date.now() - lastMove;
    if ( elapsed < 40 ) return;

    svg.select(".guideline")
        .attr("x1", d3.mouse(this)[0]-1)
        .attr("x2", d3.mouse(this)[0]-1);

    lastMove = Date.now();
});
```

This will certainly improve performance, but at the cost of making the movements more choppy. Play around with the number of milliseconds you check for. `40` may be too long.

Comment: Yes, this works. I think it is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a CSS property called `shape-rendering` which sets the priority for how your SVGs should be rendered. You can specify `auto`, `optimizeSpeed`, `crispEdges`, or `geometricPrecision`, where auto tries to accommodate speed and crispness without sacrificing precision.

I have found that settings `shape-rendering` to `auto` increased the performance of my crosshair. crispEdges and optimizeSpeed seem to make the cursor disppear intermittently. I was not able to reproduce a smooth crosshair in a fiddle, but in my solution it's actually perfectly smooth now.